# Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'XXX' at row 1

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, ubuntu, centos

My stored procedure has IN parameter for page number (`IN page INT`)
And everything works fine for any value `<= 2147483647`.
And if value is `> 2147483647` I get error `1264`.
All this happens on `5.6.26 Community Server compiled for Linux (x86_64)` and the same for `5.6.24 Community Server compiled for Win64 (x86_64)`
And all of the above is fine and I understand the error.

However, on server `5.6.30-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+2 (Ubuntu) compiled for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)` this is not reproduced. Input value is just cut to 2147483647 no matter what value I pass there.

What setting is responsible for this "auto max value cap"? How can I synchronize settings on different environments without re-installation to have the same behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: The out of range for column error message indicates that the issue is with a column, not the page parameter. I honestly think, that the error message in this case tells you exactly what the issue is: you are trying to insert a value into a field that is out of the allowed range for the field's data type. You probably have strict sql mode enabled in the server that produces the error. To be honest again, enabling strict sql mode does make sense and I would rather apply some input check than rely on mysql to truncate the data.

Comment: No, I just tried to have create empty SP (similar to the answer below) and it failed with the same error. Seems that STRICT_TRANS_TABLES controls not just table columns but SP input parameters and variable values as well because `page = page * size` fails as well if multiplication result is > 2147483647

Comment: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES indicates the strict sql mode. If you searched on mysql strct sql mode, then you would find the description of what strict sql mode does. Again: I do not think it is a good practice to disable strict sql mode. Implementing proper input checks should be the way ahead. Your code should be as independent of mysql configuration as possible.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The issue is that I didn't disable it, these are default settings in this package https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.6
I just had to install 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 and used this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [5.1.7 Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html).

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE, @@SESSION.SQL_MODE;
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE                          | @@SESSION.SQL_MODE                         |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(IN `page` INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT `page`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `sp_test`(2147483647);
+------------+
| `page`     |
+------------+
| 2147483647 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `sp_test`(2147483648);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'page' at row 1

mysql> SET @@SESSION.SQL_MODE = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE, @@SESSION.SQL_MODE;
+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE                          | @@SESSION.SQL_MODE     |
+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `sp_test`(2147483648);
+------------+
| `page`     |
+------------+
| 2147483647 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                       |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'page' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I assumed that.

On Windows I have (for both global and session) `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

On CentOS I have `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

And on Ubuntu I have just `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

So `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` seems to control that. Why is this so different for the same 5.6 version? :)